# Can I convert $2\cos x$ to $\sin \dfrac{x}{2}$?

Tags: trigonometry

Can I convert $2\cos x$ to $\sin \dfrac{x}{2}$? Or at least $-2+2 \cos x$ to $\sin $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left|\sin\frac x2\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Neither of those is a valid substitution. For the first, observe that, at $x = 0$, we have
$$
2\cos 0 = 2\\
\sin \dfrac{0}{2} = 0.
$$
For the second, look at $x = \pi$ and notice that
$$
-2 + 2 \cos \pi = -4 \\
\sin \dfrac{\pi}{2} = 1.
$$

Comment: I have edited my question, with the task I actually need to solve. Can You help?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange. As a general rule, substantially modifying a question after folks have answered is considered impolite: you make it look as if they're foolishly failing to answer your question. Better (in the future) to post a new question rather than doing this. I'll let someone else answer your revised question.

Comment: I can make a new question, it's not a problem